# Jersey Client unit test

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jersey-client

I have setup a Jersey Resource which returns a List perfectly in the browser. But i cant get it to run in my Unit test. I do get the error message:

```
A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<at.sunfinder.dto.Location>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

I append my classes in the following

Resource:

```
@GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<Location> getWeather(@QueryParam("latitude") double latitude, @QueryParam("longitude") double longitude,
            @QueryParam("radius") int radius, @QueryParam("countryCode") String countryCode /* Datum */) {

        setWeatherController(new WeatherControllerImpl());      
        return weatherController.getWeather(latitude, longitude, radius, countryCode);
    }
```

Location DTO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Location {

    private String location;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private Weather weather;

    @XmlTransient
    private Date lastUpdate;

    public Location(){}

    public Location(double latitude, double longitude, String location, Weather weather, Date lastUpdate){
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.location = location;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="location")
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="latitude")
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="longitude")
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="weather")
    public Weather getWeather(){
        return weather;
    }   
}
```

And my Unit Test:

```
@Test
    public void testGetWeather(){       

        Client client = Client.create();         


        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url); 
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

        List<Location> locations = null;

        if(response.getClientResponseStatus() == ClientResponse.Status.OK){
            locations = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Location>>(){});
        }

        assertTrue(locations.size()> 0);
    }
```

My pom xml has the following dependencies:
            
                com.sun.jersey
                jersey-server
                1.18.1

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your test is requesting *application/json* format but your Location DTO isn't able to parse it. Try changing the test to request *application/xml*, i.e.:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Alternatively, make sure your DTO can parse json as well (by providing @JsonProperty annotations).